# Get only a subset of fields from a Kafka topic using Apache Beam

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-beam

Is there a way to read only specific fields of a Kafka topic?

I have a topic, say `person` with a schema `personSchema`. The schema contains many fields such as `id`, `name`, `address`, `contact`, `dateOfBirth`.

I want to get only `id`, `name` and `address`. How can I do that?

Currently I´m reading streams using Apache Beam and intend to write data to BigQuery afterwards. I am trying to use `Filter` but cannot get it to work because of Boolean return type

Here´s my code:

```
Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create();
PCollection<KV<String, Person>> kafkaStreams =
                pipeline
               .apply("read streams", dataIO.readStreams(topic))
               .apply(Filter.by(new SerializableFunction<KV<String, Person>, Boolean>() {
                  @Override
                  public Boolean apply(KV<String, Order> input) {
                     return input.getValue().get("address").equals(true);
                  }
                  }));
```

where `dataIO.readStreams` is returning this:

```
return KafkaIO.<String, Person>read()
                .withTopic(topic)
                .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                .withValueDeserializer(PersonAvroDeserializer.class)
                .withConsumerConfigUpdates(consumer)
                .withoutMetadata();
```

I would appreciate suggestions for a possible solution.

Comment: You should implement your own ValueDeserializer to read only the fields you need, and maybe also use you own class instead of Person. Something like smallPerson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this by creating a new `TableSchema` by yourself with only the required fields. Later when you write to BigQuery, you can pass the newly created schema as an argument instead of the old one.

```
        TableSchema schema = new TableSchema();
        List<TableFieldSchema> tableFields = new ArrayList<TableFieldSchema>();

        TableFieldSchema id =
                new TableFieldSchema()
                        .setName("id")
                        .setType("STRING")
                        .setMode("NULLABLE");

        tableFields.add(id);
       
        schema.setFields(tableFields);
        return schema;
```

I should also mention that if you are converting an AVRO record to BigQuery´s `TableRow` at some point, you may need to implement some checks there too.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [ksqlDB](https://ksqldb.io/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-07-15&utm_term=rmoff-devx), which also work directly with [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-07-15&utm_term=rmoff-devx) for which there is a [sink connector for BigQuery](https://www.confluent.io/hub/wepay/kafka-connect-bigquery?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-07-15&utm_term=rmoff-devx)

```sql
CREATE STREAM MY_SOURCE WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='person', VALUE_FORMAT=AVRO');

CREATE STREAM FILTERED_STREAM AS SELECT id, name, address FROM MY_SOURCE;

CREATE SINK CONNECTOR SINK_BQ_01 WITH (
  'connector.class' = 'com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkConnector',
  'topics' = 'FILTERED_STREAM',
…
);
```